# How to restore the backup messages in a queue

Tags: ibm-mq

We have currently using IBM MQ 7.5.0.8 version,in windows machine,as per my application requirement we have to take message backup and restore the messages in different queue and queue manager, so we have taken message backup with qload command but we dont know how to restore the message in another queue manger.
my question is how to restore the message in a queue,if any command for restore the messages kindly share me command or process..

@joshMc Thanks for replay.
Given below flags are used for with in the same queue manger we can process it.
but my requirement is we have taken messages backup from QM1 queue manager in UAT server. we need to restore this message in fallback server QM2 Queue manager.

@joshMc
Thank you josh issue got resolved i was tried with qload -m QM2( target qmgr name) - o target queue name -f( my file path)
messages are restored in target queue

Comment: Just change the flag for the queue name from `-i` or `-I` to `-o` for output.   You can run with `-?` for all options.  Note V8 and later come with `dmpmqmsg` as part of the base product and it can read files produced by `qload`.

Comment: Why would it not work.  You would only need to specify a different `-m` parameter with the second queue manager name.   What problem are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using QLoad from SupportPac MO03 or the commercial release from MQGem?

In either case, they come with a manual that details all of the input/output parameters.  Here is an IBM support page with examples of QLoad: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21585718

But the best place to look for help is in the PDF manual that QLoad comes with. As they say: RTM.